# How to do multiple if else statements in React?

Tags: html, facebook, reactjs, if-statement

So I am trying to create an if else statement similar too the following in React...

(where aNumber is any number)

```
if(aNumber < 5){
    show a picture
}else if (aNumber < 10){
    show a different picture
}else if (aNumber < 15){
    show another different picture
}else{
    show a some other 4th picture
}
```

In my table this.state.sWA1 returns a wind speed, so If its above a certain value I want to show a different picture depending on how high the wind speed is

```
<td>{this.state.sWA1 > '15' ? <img src={require('../arrowUp.png')} /> : <img src={require('../arrowDown.png')} /> }</td>
```

This currently works but I can only seem to find help with one if else statement rather than several if else statements, can anyone help  or suggest an alternative approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's called [conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

```
<div>
  { this.state.sWA1>15 && 
  <div>
    //show picture
  </div>}
  { this.state.sWA1>5 && this.state.sWA1<15
  <div>
    //show picture
  </div>}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the if statement, you can create an array to map the corresponding image.

```
const windLevels = [
  { value: 5, img: 'a.png' },
  { value: 10, img: 'b.png' },
  { value: 15, img: 'c.png' },
  { value: Infinity, img: 'd.png' }
]

const getImgSrc = (level) =>
  windLevels.find(w => w.value > level).img

// in your render function
// you get c.png
<img src={getImgSrc(13)} />
```

With this pattern you can see that the code becomes very clean.

Note that IE doesn't support `find()`, but you can add a polyfill for that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! that works for when I put in 13, but when I put in <img src={getImgSrc({this.state.sWA1})} />, this.state.sWA1 returns a number, it says "Unexpected token, expected ," ... any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: `Unexpected token, ...` means you have syntax error somewhere

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution;

```
statement (aNumber) {
    if..
      return ..
  }

{this.statement()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function to make the code more clear and use as many conditions as you want, call a `function` for `image src`:

```
<td><img src={this._checkCondition()} /></td>
```

Inside that `function` check the condition and `return` the image:

```
_checkCondition(){
    let img;
    if(aNumber < 5){
        img = '../a';
    }else if (aNumber < 10){
        img = '../b';
    }else if (aNumber < 15){
        img = '../c';
    }else{
        img = '../d';
    }
    return require(img);   
}
```

You can call this `function` inside `require` also:

```
src={require(this._checkCondition())}

_checkCondition(){
    let img;
    if(aNumber < 5){
        img = '';
    }else if (aNumber < 10){
        img = '';
    }else if (aNumber < 15){
        img = '';
    }else{
        img = '';
    }
    return img;  
}
```

Check this example:

```js
var a = [
  'http://closethegapca.org/wp-content/plugins/itro-popup/images/close-icon.png',
  'http://servemeright.com.au/smr-web/serve-me-right-logo.png',
  'https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/add-button-cross-in-a-circle_318-9475.jpg',
  'http://static.wixstatic.com/media/38246828849b1ecf8ee948eb6c273d30.wix_mp_256',
  'http://photos.merinews.com/upload/imageGallery/bigImage/1286272891909-greenery.jpg'
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        value: 1,
    };
  }
  
  _onclick(i){
     this.setState({value: i})
  }
  
  _checkCondition(){
     let img, value = this.state.value;
     if(value < 10)
         img = a[0];
     else if(value > 10 && value < 20)
         img = a[1];
     else if(value > 20 && value < 30)
         img = a[2];
     else if(value > 30 && value < 40)
         img = a[3];
     else
         img = a[4];
     return img;
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
             <ul>
                 {[1,15,25,35,45].map((el,i)=>{
                     return <li key={i} onClick={this._onclick.bind(this,el)}>Item: {el}</li>
                 })}
             </ul>
             <div>* Click on items to change the image</div>
             <div>Image No: {this.state.value}</div>            
             <img style={{width: '100px'}} src={this._checkCondition()}/>
       </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! But that produces "Unexpected token, expected ; "

Comment: after _checkCondition(){    its says expects ;

Comment: check the updated answer, use it in a similar way it will work :)